# Symfony 2 guide for Django developers

Tags: django, symfony

After 8 years of PHP development, I switched to python 2 years ago, as much as I loved coding with Django, there are more jobs in PHP than Python in New Zealand (not to mention .NET), I have started to read about Symfony 2. Been through the "The Big Picture" tutorial and it seems very familiar to Django.

Question: Is there a migration guide for Django developers? So it can speed up the learning process?

Searching "Symfony for Django" in Google returns non-relevant results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a framework seemed to Django in PHP. Is almost impossible because of the languages features. I respect the the opinion of everyone and I'm not to judge but, I'm a a Django developer and I tried Symfony2 and didn't like it much. Specially because there are many configuration files in many formats and It seemed to me a framework for building a C++ application.

I tried [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and was pretty happy with it. As happy as you can be with PHP of course. It uses lot of the last features of PHP 5, configuration files are just `.php` files (just as Django's are `.py`) and have a very declarative syntax.

The docs are fine, not as great as Django's (I didn't think at the moment that the docs for Symfony2 are great either), and not to mention the framework is 1.5 mb, compared to 70mb+ that is Symfony (with vendors).

To answer your question, there aren't migration guides (because IMHO is impossible to do a straightforward migration). As a Django developer, you must be familiarized with MV* patterns, Symfony2 uses the same approach, MVP pattern, this means won't be hard to you to get it. Basically is the same as Django (far far away really :) ), you have a model, a controller, and the views. You do your business logic in the controller (`DefaultController.php` is the default for each bundle), you code there a method for each view (usually) which must return a rendered template.

You declare your models in `yaml, xml or php with annotations` and sync your db with them. This create model objects for you so you can query them in your controller. As you can see, conceptually is the same approach.

Hope this helps! I'll receive a lot of hate from Symfony2 people but is just my opinion.

Good luck :)

Comment: +1 for mention [Laravel](http://laravel.com) framework ;)

Comment: Business logic should go to the model, not controllers. Model is not only the data access layer. Laravel uses Symfony btw (in its own weird way - all those statics...).

Comment: I see why you don't like it, I read through the start up guide and already got lost in the filename references. From a django dev point of view, I have to write so much more in symfony, and the hate you gonna get from ppl are probably haven't worked with django before.

Comment: @JakubZalas you're right. Only that adding logic to Models in Symfony2 is also cumbersome because they get modified constantly when you generate them from changing `.yml` files. Laravel uses HttpFoundation from Symfony, which is a nice piece of code. The problem IMHO with Symfony is that there is too much bureaucracy for getting the job done. Such a **big** framework and the Symfony2 book is 246 pages. Django ref is 1174 pages (that's real documentation). That was my problem with Symfony, used Django before.

Comment: Please stop talking about Symfony without knowing what it is. Symfony is only about the view and controllers. Models are up to developer to implement. Symfony standard edition comes with Doctrine, that's true - and that's what you're talking about when taking about generating .yml. However, your model is NOT ONLY the data access layer!

Answer (score 3):

No. There isn't.

You'll have to work with [the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) (which are awesome btw).